# how to detect the delete item action using a workflow sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-workflow

I need to detect when an item is delete it, to get some information for that item, but I can't use Visual Studio to create something to get this information, so the only thing I can use is a workflow, but I have no idea of how to achieve this or if is it possible to do it using workflows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to assign workflow to delete item action. But you can create custom action which starts a workflow and then deletes an item. You can check this [tutorial](http://blogs.sharepoint911.com/blogs/jennifer/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=126e87c2-6987-4652-a0af-425b31d827bd&ID=50&Web=2d9e5740-0f11-4705-b67c-010879b6e2a9)